# How to add timeout function to a response method after the root file is loaded in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to use a setTimeout function to make a redirection after the root file has been displayed in express js
example:

```
app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render('index');
    setTimeout(()=>{
     res.render('homepage');
   },3000)
  }
```

but it seems not to work

Answer (score 0):

You can only render one file. If you want to redirect after it has been displayed, your index file should have some javascript, such as:

```
<script>

setTimeout(() => {
  location.pathname = '/homepage';
}, 3000);

</script>
```

Comment: yes this works and sorry i forgot to mention the file is an ejs file it redirects alright but the content does not display.

Comment: You would need in express your `app.get('/homepage', ...` to do the `res.render('homepage')`

Comment: Am not sure I get you

Comment: You have `app.get('/')` for `res.render('index')`. You need another one for the homepage. Otherwise it doesn't know what you want to do when you go to `/homepage` (it would return a 404).

Comment: Awesome it works
thanks